# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' error in my pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

after running my code i got this kind of error, can anyone help me fix it please. The error starts after putting a code to filter if the email is duplicate or not in the database.

here is the error i got:

[image: img]

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$name = @$_POST['name'];
$age = @$_POST['age'];
$address = @$_POST['address'];
$gender = @$_POST['gender'];
$email = @$_POST['email'];

        $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE email = :email ";

        $dupesql = $dbc->prepare($dupesql);
        $dupesql->bindParam(':name', $email);
        $dupesql->execute();
        $num_rows = $dupesql->rowCount(); 

        if($num_rows === 0) 
        {
        echo "1";
        $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, email ) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :email)";

        $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
        $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
        $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);

        $results = $query->execute();


        }else{
        echo "0";
        exit;
        }       

?>
```

Comment: `$dupesql->bindParam(':name', $email);` ? It should ':email'

Comment: @1nflktd oh thanks i missed it...put it in answer so i can vote it

Comment: Why didn't you catch the exception? Why's there silencing operator in front of $_POST? Why do you use bindParam and not bindValue? Do you know the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are facing this error because you are using a wrong parameter in your query.

```
$dupesql->bindParam(':name', $email);
```

`:name` doesn't exists so it should `:email`.